# rails how to export data to excel

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have table like the following
[image]

now, i want to export this to excel, so i can open it in ms excel

Answer (score 3):

You can use [FasterCSV](http://fastercsv.rubyforge.org/) gem.

You can either use `to_csv` method.

```
def index
  @records = ....
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :xml => @records }
    format.csv  { @records.to_csv }
  end
end
```

or customize the output and use `send_data` method in the controller.

```
format.csv do
  csv_string = FasterCSV.generate do |csv|
    # header row
    csv << ["id", "Column1", "Column1"]
    # data rows
    @records.each do |r|
      csv << [r.id, r.column1, r.column2]
    end
  # send it to the browser
  send_data csv_string,
            :type => 'text/csv; charset=iso-8859-1; header=present',
            :disposition => "attachment; filename=records.csv"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I would advice to use [Spreadsheet](http://spreadsheet.rubyforge.org/_index.html) which is mature. I'm using it with Rails 3 with no problems.

The overall process would be:

```
book = Spreadsheet::Workbook.new
sheet = book.create_worksheet :name => 'Customers'
sheet.row(0).concat %w{Name Country Acknowlegement}
book.write '/path/to/output/excel-file.xls'
```

Comment: Mature with a 0.x version number. hmmmm

Comment: Spreadsheet works great for me, too, until the size of the worksheet gets too big.  It still works, but is really slow creating XLS file after db queries have finished.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby 1.9 has a built in CSV library with very similar API as the FasterCSV gem (actually the gem got integrated into Ruby!).